# I want to detect PDF text with Cloud Vision API and get the result from Google Cloud Storage

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-vision

I want filename of vision API result, but I don't know how to get.

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client libraries
const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision').v1;

// Creates a client
const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();

const gcsSourceUri = `gs://${bucketName}/${fileName}`;
const gcsDestinationUri = `gs://${bucketName}/${outputPrefix}/`;

const inputConfig = {
  // Supported mime_types are: 'application/pdf' and 'image/tiff'
  mimeType: 'application/pdf',
  gcsSource: {
    uri: gcsSourceUri,
  },
};
const outputConfig = {
  gcsDestination: {
    uri: gcsDestinationUri,
  },
};
const features = [{type: 'DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION'}];
const request = {
  requests: [
    {
      inputConfig: inputConfig,
      features: features,
      outputConfig: outputConfig,
    },
  ],
};

const [operation] = await client.asyncBatchAnnotateFiles(request);
const [filesResponse] = await operation.promise();
const destinationUri =
  filesResponse.responses[0].outputConfig.gcsDestination.uri;
console.log('Json saved to: ' + destinationUri);
```

"destinationUri" don't include filename.
For example, when gcsDestinationUri is`gs:/*****/index/`, destinationUri is `gs:/*****/index`.
But, the file saved as result in GCS is `output-1-to-1.json`.

I searched operation Obj and filesResponse Obj, I could not find it.

Who knows my problem??

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documentation the filename will be in the form `output-x-to-y`

> gcsDestination.uri - a valid Google Cloud Storage URI. The bucket must
> be writeable by the user or service account making the request. The
> filename will be output-x-to-y, where x and y represent the PDF/TIFF
> page numbers included in that output file. If the file exists, its
> contents will be overwritten.

`But, the file saved as result in GCS is output-1-to-1.json.`

Therefore I think that everything worked as expected and you can not change the name of the file.